# Trouble adding an object to a collection in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a small application in excel to track the progress of a scout badge.
I have a Challenge object comprising an integer and a string.
I have a ChallengeList object comprising a list of challenge objects.
I can read the list of challenges (32 of them) from a sheet into the collection and a debug.print check shows that the challenge objects are created correctly.

I add the object to the collection but when I 'for each' the items in the collection and print them the collection seems to consist of 32 copies of the last item. This is also the case is I read the object using item(x).

I suspect that I am doing something stupid with adding the object to the collection but I cannot see what. I have read, re-read and spoken to the duck. I am officially lost. Can anyone here suggest what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub loadChallenges()
    Dim tempChal As challenge
    Set m_chalList = New Collection
    lineNum = 2

    Set tempChal = New challenge
    currentCell = Sheets("Challenges").Cells(lineNum, 1)
    Do
        'create Challenge object
        tempChal.ID = Sheets("Challenges").Cells(lineNum, 1)
        tempChal.challengeName = Sheets("Challenges").Cells(lineNum, 2)
        'add challenge object to array
        m_chalList.Add tempChal
        lineNum = lineNum + 1
        Debug.Print tempChal.toString 'check object
    Loop Until Len(Sheets("Challenges").Cells(lineNum, 2)) = 0

    'check collection
    For Each tempChal In m_chalList
        Debug.Print tempChal.toString
    Next

End Sub
```

Debug.print Output:

ID: 1
challengeName: In a hammock

....

ID: 32
challengeName: Plan, deliver and review Lightweight Night Away

Check Collection output is 32 instances of the line below.

ID: 32
challengeName: Plan, deliver and review Lightweight Night Away

Comment: I assume `challenge` is a class module.  That being the case, I think you need to move `Set tempChal = New challenge` to the top of the `Do` loop (after the `Do`), so you are creating a new object for each iteration for the loop.

Comment: You need to create new objects, as it is you're holding 32 references to the same object in your collection.

Comment: Thanks.
I moved the Set command into the loop and it works perfectly.
I should have spotted it and so should my rubber duck. I have spent days on this.

Thanks Ron and Nacorid.